# How to assign a Python list to a vim variable and escape its strings correctly

Tags: vimscript-python, escape, string-manipulation

Here is a Python list that I'm trying to assign to some Vim variable.

```
lines = ['"""Something foo\'s thing."""', '', 'foo = "asdfasdf" \\', 'bar']
command = 'let l:corrected_lines = {lines}'.format(lines=lines)
vim.eval(command)
```

And then in a caller function, I use `l:corrected_lines` to do some extra work.

The problem is that there are 2 issues with the string above

- The single quote `foo's` apparently needs to be escaped
- The `\` also needs to be escaped

Apparently Vim escapes single-quotes by placing two of them side-by-side, like this `''`. So I've experimented with running `replace("\\'", "''")` and other combinations of methods. Also Vim changes the `\` in the source-code to `\\` so I've tried adding `replace('\\\\', '\\')` and that works. The problem is that these replacements work in isolation but don't work together.

I feel like there's probably a simpler way to escape this line but I haven't had success with Python or using Vim's `:escape()` command. Can someone please suggest a solution?

Note: Just to make `lines` make a bit more sense visually, this is how `lines` looks like printed out

```
"""Something foo's thing."""

foo = "asdfasdf" \
bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pyeval()`, `py3eval()`, or `pyxeval()` to read python variables into vim:

python:

```
x = [1,2,3]
vim.command('let X = pyeval("x")')
```

vim:

```
py x = [1,2,3]
let X = pyeval('x')
```