# How to set internal vim variable from python code

Tags: vimscript-python

I'm trying to write vim plugin for easier work with cmake. I want it to read some values from json file: build_dir, generator, cmake VARS and then give vim user few functions: configure, build, maybe run.

I decided to use python, because it's easy to run cmake from it and easy to parse json. But i have problem with understanding where i need to save values from json.

I decided to just save them to vim variables, `g:cmake_configuration_name` for example. But i didn't find way to do this. I read `help python` few times already and tried to google it, no luck.

Maybe that's just bad way to do this, so i need help with this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vim plugin with python, you may first import the `vim` module (see `:h python-vim`).

```
import vim
```

Then there is `vim.command(cmd)` to execute an Ex command, so in your case

```
vim.command('let g:cmake_configuration_name=' + python_variable)
```

should do the job.

Comment: This I imagine would be very inefficient for large list like objects. Is there a better way? Edit: Yes, there is. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20404/33130